# OpenCV Help - Error: no operator "=" Matches these operands. operand types are cv::Mat = IplImage*

Tags: c++, opencv, cascade-classifier

I have recently started learning how to use OpenCV and i have been following the tutorials hosted by their website. I am using OpenCV 3.0, however, it seems some of the tutorial information is out of date.

I and on the tutorial "Cascade Classifier" link: 
http://www.docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

They provided example code is not running for me and I cannot understand why. I have provided the code example below:

```
 #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 /** Function Headers */
 void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );

 /** Global variables */
 String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
 String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
 CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
 CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
 string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
 RNG rng(12345);

 /** @function main */
 int main( int argc, const char** argv )
 {
   CvCapture* capture;
   Mat frame;

   //-- 1. Load the cascades
   if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
   if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

   //-- 2. Read the video stream
   capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
   if( capture )
   {
     while( true )
     {
   frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

   //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
       if( !frame.empty() )
       { detectAndDisplay( frame ); }
       else
       { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }

       int c = waitKey(10);
       if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
      }
   }
   return 0;
 }

/** @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
  std::vector<Rect> faces;
  Mat frame_gray;

  cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

  //-- Detect faces
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;

    //-- In each face, detect eyes
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
 {
   Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
   int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
   circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
 }
  }
  //-- Show what you got
  imshow( window_name, frame );
 }
```

The error for me arises on line 38 "frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );"
the "=" is underlined red and gives the error message displayed in the title of the question

I'm sorry if the code is not displayed correctly, this is my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

no fear, it's not exactly your fault, - you stumbled over outdated tutorial code, the arcane c-api is no more adequate today(and won't work with 3.0).

please replace :

```
   CvCapture* capture;
   capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
   if( capture )
   {
```

with:

```
   VideoCapture capture(-1);
   if (capture.isOpened())
   {
```

and:

```
   frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

with:

```
   capture.read(frame);
```

also, opencv3.0 docs: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/

(your sample code is from 2.4.x)

Comment: Oh my god, thanks you so much for the swift reply, I really appreciate it.

I feel stupid now for not realising i had stumbled across old documentation.

Comment: the sooner we erase all IplImages from this site, - the better ;)